# How to get my page content with embedly? What is the requirements for my page?

Tags: embedly

I want to read my page content via embedly.
I tried something like just call this URL

https://api.embed.ly/1/extract?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fmy_page.html&key=2222222

and my page is very simple just like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Text 1</div>
<p>Text 2P</p>
<body>
</html>
```

but content result attribute is always empty. I can get title, but not a content. I was expecting to get this in the content field

```
<div>Text 1</div>
<p>Text 2P</p>
```

, but it is empty.

From other side, if I try to get my blog's content from blogspot.com in the same way, it works fine.

How can I fix it? Maybe my page is not formatted properly, in this case what should be proper format of my page?

Answer (score 0):

I think it only extracts the content when it is inside an article tag. For instance this link works fine [Embed.ly Content](http://embed.ly/docs/explore/extract?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2013%2F03%2F26%2Fembedly-now-goes-beyond-embedding-with-new-products-extract-display-for-making-sense-of-links-resizing-images%2F)

Answer (score 0):

Embedly reads from the `meta tags`. Your blogger url has all relevant meta tags included, so the preview renders.

Try adding `meta` tags such as `description , title & author` in your page and try again.

This link `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_meta_tags.htm` gives you more detail about meta tags.